# Unable to build an .EXE for .NET version 1.1.4322 using vbc?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have installed ***Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1*** in my laptop. I want to build an .exe file for my VB.NET application **sample.vb**.

i tried to build an .EXE using visual basic compiler(vbc) then i changed my command prompt path to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322`
and executed following command

```
  vbc /r:System.dll /t:exe "D:\sample.vb"
```

i got the output as below:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic .NET Compiler version 7.10.3052.4
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 1.1.4322.573
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 1987-2002. All rights reserved.

vbc : Command line error BC2012 : can't open 'sample.vb' for writing
```

i don't know why it is giving me the `command line error BC2012` error and what am i missing. i have checked the `vbc` and `system.dll` files in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322` directory, they are existing.

Any one please help me to build an .EXE to target .NET version 1.1

Comment: This is usually the error you get when you try to build a project that is already running. Do you have a startup script launching the application by any chance?

Comment: Man you are lucky. You run an OS that can do that old stuff. Ouch. What interest do you have in something that ancient -there is nothing to be learned from .NET 1.1 these days.

Comment: The copyright is funny, an Oracle product might get in the way :)  Best to use /out explicitly perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vbc /r:System.dll "D:\sample.vb" /out:"D:\sample.exe"
```